# Como editar o teclado do editTexte para ocupar menos espaço?

Tags: android, xml

Eu tenho vários `editText`, quando chama o teclado ele comprime todos junto com o botão tem como resolver isso.

Comment: Mostre seu código.

Comment: ah! esqueci de comentar na pergunta, isso ocorre quando coloco um banner de anuncio, sem o banner funciona.

Comment: Mostre o código XML

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi direito mas veja se não é o caso de setar isso no EditText:

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```